How to run docker image on cloud9 with s3 input files
I am new in AWS and docker field. I have several question regarding run the docker on aws.
I pull the fastqc public image and then login ECR. Further i tag image and push into ECR repo. Now i want to fastqc tool through this docker image on aws cloud9 using aws batch.
Is there anyone who can explain me how can i run this docker with input file in s3 storage,
Thanks & Regards,
Deepika
I am confused that how can i run docker image with as batch. so want to learn it.
